# Неограниченное число в Android Studio

Tags: android

Существует ли способ задать число больше чем long в Android Studio ? Думал через строку, но хотелось бы способ полегче, т.к. к числу будет постоянно что-то прибавляться или вычитаться.

Comment: Попробуйте BigDecimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать класс BigInteger для целых чисел и BigDecimal для чисел с точками. Оба класса определены в пакете java.math.

Пример:

```
 BigInteger numBig1 = new BigInteger ("1234567890123456890");
 BigInteger numBig2 = new BigInteger ("6456484464684864865");
```

Для того, чтобы, например, суммировать их, можно использовать метод add():

```
BigInteger sum = numBig1.add(numBig2);
```

Чтобы отнять - метод subtract():

```
BigInteger subst = numBig1.subtract(numBig2);
```

Для умножения - метод multiply():

```
BigInteger mult = numBig1.multiply(numBig2);
```